# Add custom attribute to OpenAPI specification file and swagger in .net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a .Net Core 5 Web API project (C#) where I've added and configured Swagger.Net. Everything works fine, but now the client has asked me to add a "custom attribute" in the OAS file to specify that the APIs are not yet ready in production:

```
x-acme-production-ready=false
```

As of today I have always provided the json file automatically produced by Swagger.

How can I produce the OAS file with a structure like this:

```
openapi: "3.0.0"

# REQUIRED - Formal commitments from the API focal point
x-acme-api-commitments:
  api-100: We commit to providing a proper valid OpenAPI (swagger) specification file for each API change.....

# REQUIRED - List of versions changes
x-acme-api-changelog: 
  - version: 1.0.0
    changes: Add GET /example
  - version: 1.1.0
    changes: Add POST /example

info: 
  # REQUIRED - Functional descriptive name of the API. 
  title: ACME - Basic template API
```

The above file looks like is a text representation of the JSON, so maybe should be enough to add the custom field *x-acme-production-ready* to the JSON, but how can I add it programmatically?

********* UPDATE ***********

Looking at the specification above this custom field should be added at the same level of the tag "info" in the JSON swagger:

```
   openapi: "3.0.1",
   x-acme-production-ready: "true",
   info: {
       title: "my-app-title",
       version: "v1.0"
   },
   servers: [
       {
           url: "https://localhost:44370"
       }
   ],
   paths: {...}
```

I have added the class CustomModelDocumentFilter to my project, but I can't understand how and where to call it, and how to use it for adding that field in that position.

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyApp.Swagger
{
    public class CustomModelDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            swaggerDoc....
        }
    }
}
```

In my startup I have:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
       {
          c.DocumentFilter<Swagger.CustomModelDocumentFilter>();
          c.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "my app title", Version = "v1.0", Description = "my app description." });

          string xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
          string xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);

       });
```

Comment: By "Swagger.Net" do you mean [Swagger-Net](https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net) or [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore)?

Comment: @Helen I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Answer (score 0):

If you use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, you can use a [document filter](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#document-filters) to customise the OpenAPI document.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seems it could be the case but I can't really understand how it should be used, where I have to call it...